# Conditional Jquery validation before submitting

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm fairly new to using Jquery validation plug in so here's what I'm trying to do. There are two sets of addresses. One is the physical address fields while the other is the mailing address fields.

If the user fills in the physical address fields then checks the box - is the mailing address the same as the physical address? If yes, then disable - gray out the box.

The form is submitted the data is fine.

What I'm struggling with is, if the user unchecks the box then the fields must be filled in and the form is submitted. It should save. So I created a custom validation for the jquery plugin as follows:

```
$('form').validate({


    rules: {

        ResidentalMailing: { validateMailing: true }

    },
    messages: {
        ResidentalMailing: {
            required: "You must fill in the mailing address if it is not the same as the physical address."

        }
    }


});
```

The Actual Custom Validator:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("validateMailing", function(value, element) {

        // if it is unchcked
        if (!$('#ResidentalMailing').is(':checked')) {

            // change each field to yellow
            $(".mailingaddy").each(function () {

                $(this).css('background-color', '#ffff00');

            });

            // if the first field has a vlue of greater than one - data is there.
            if ($('#Address1').val().length > 0) {

                // it's okay to submit
                return true;

            }

            // it's not okay to submit.
            return false;

        } else {

            // if chcked.
            $(".mailingaddy").each(function () {

                // remove the yellow back ground
                $(this).css('background-color', 'transparent');
                // set it to grayed out/disabled
                $(this).attr("disabled", true);

            });

            // it's okay to submit.
            return true;

        }

}, "You must fill in the mailing address fields.");
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing. I tried the depends route but it did not work.

In a nutshell - I'm trying to allow a submission only if certain crtierias are met...

Comment: What are the symptoms?  Do you get console errors?  Does the validation not run?  or does it run but not actually validate?  More info would be helpful

Comment: No errors - the validation runs properly when the box is checked but it does not run when the box is unchecked and at the first field has value in it. No console errors .. And